# schroot fails to mount on entry

Tags: linux, chroot

I'm trying to setup a chroot environment for myself, and it is failing. This has been reproduced on multiple versions (10.04 and 11.04) of Ubuntu. I set it up by doing:

```
$ mkdir -p /srv/chroot/squeeze64
$ debootstrap --arch amd64 squeeze /srv/chroot/squeeze64 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/
$ cat /etc/schroot/schroot.conf
    [squeeze64]
    description=Whatever
    directory=/srv/chroot/squeeze64
    users=ajtack
    root-users=ajtack
    type=directory
```

Entry to the chroot fails as:

```
$ schroot -c squeeze64
E: Failed to change to directory '/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-d1d6ed5e-b217-4319-94ee-ff0422a75671': No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure how to debug this. What's gone wrong?

---

Additional information: From a verbose run.

```
$ schroot --verbose -c squeeze64
I: Executing ‘00check setup-start ok’
I: 00check: STAGE=setup-start
I: 00check: STATUS=ok
I: 00check: AUTH_GID=1000
I: 00check: AUTH_HOME=/home/ajtack
I: 00check: AUTH_RGID=1000
I: 00check: AUTH_RGROUP=ajtack
I: 00check: AUTH_RUID=1000
I: 00check: AUTH_RUSER=ajtack
I: 00check: AUTH_SHELL=/bin/bash
I: 00check: AUTH_UID=1000
I: 00check: AUTH_USER=ajtack
I: 00check: AUTH_VERBOSITY=verbose
I: 00check: CHROOT_DESCRIPTION=Squeeze64 (session chroot)
I: 00check: CHROOT_DIRECTORY=/srv/chroot/squeeze64
I: 00check: CHROOT_MOUNT_LOCATION=/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 00check: CHROOT_NAME=squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 00check: CHROOT_PATH=/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 00check: CHROOT_SCRIPT_CONFIG=/etc/schroot/default/config
I: 00check: CHROOT_SESSION_CLONE=false
I: 00check: CHROOT_SESSION_CREATE=false
I: 00check: CHROOT_SESSION_PURGE=false
I: 00check: CHROOT_TYPE=directory
I: 00check: CHROOT_UNION_TYPE=none
I: 00check: DATA_DIR=/usr/share/schroot
I: 00check: HOST=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
I: 00check: HOST_CPU=x86_64
I: 00check: HOST_OS=linux-gnu
I: 00check: HOST_VENDOR=pc
I: 00check: LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/lib/schroot
I: 00check: MOUNT_DIR=/var/lib/schroot/mount
I: 00check: PID=25954
I: 00check: PLATFORM=linux
I: 00check: PWD=/
I: 00check: SESSION_ID=squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 00check: SETUP_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/schroot/setup
I: 00check: SYSCONF_DIR=/etc/schroot
I: 00check: VERBOSE=verbose
I: Executing ‘05file setup-start ok’
I: Executing ‘15killprocs setup-start ok’
I: Executing ‘99check setup-start ok’
E: Failed to change to directory ‘/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6’: No such file or directory
I: Executing ‘99check setup-stop ok’
I: 99check: STAGE=setup-stop
I: 99check: STATUS=ok
I: 99check: AUTH_GID=1000
I: 99check: AUTH_HOME=/home/ajtack
I: 99check: AUTH_RGID=1000
I: 99check: AUTH_RGROUP=ajtack
I: 99check: AUTH_RUID=1000
I: 99check: AUTH_RUSER=ajtack
I: 99check: AUTH_SHELL=/bin/bash
I: 99check: AUTH_UID=1000
I: 99check: AUTH_USER=ajtack
I: 99check: AUTH_VERBOSITY=verbose
I: 99check: CHROOT_DESCRIPTION=Squeeze64 (session chroot)
I: 99check: CHROOT_DIRECTORY=/srv/chroot/squeeze64
I: 99check: CHROOT_MOUNT_LOCATION=/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 99check: CHROOT_NAME=squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 99check: CHROOT_PATH=/var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 99check: CHROOT_SCRIPT_CONFIG=/etc/schroot/default/config
I: 99check: CHROOT_SESSION_CLONE=false
I: 99check: CHROOT_SESSION_CREATE=false
I: 99check: CHROOT_SESSION_PURGE=false
I: 99check: CHROOT_TYPE=directory
I: 99check: CHROOT_UNION_TYPE=none
I: 99check: DATA_DIR=/usr/share/schroot
I: 99check: HOST=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
I: 99check: HOST_CPU=x86_64
I: 99check: HOST_OS=linux-gnu
I: 99check: HOST_VENDOR=pc
I: 99check: LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/lib/schroot
I: 99check: MOUNT_DIR=/var/lib/schroot/mount
I: 99check: PID=25954
I: 99check: PLATFORM=linux
I: 99check: PWD=/
I: 99check: SESSION_ID=squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: 99check: SETUP_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/schroot/setup
I: 99check: SYSCONF_DIR=/etc/schroot
I: 99check: VERBOSE=verbose
I: Executing ‘15killprocs setup-stop ok’
I: 15killprocs: Killing processes run inside /var/lib/schroot/mount/squeeze64-1d8d6547-8c33-4b96-a82e-d97d697d08e6
I: Executing ‘05file setup-stop ok’
I: Executing ‘00check setup-stop ok’
```

Comment: The base system is 64bit right?  You aren't trying to run a 64bit chroot on a 32bit OS?

Comment: Yes, the base system is definitely 64-bit.

Comment: Is there something I can add to this, to help resolve? This is a showstopper for me, and I haven't been able to work around it.

Comment: What happens if you run schroot with the `--verbose` option?  What happens if you run `sudo chroot /srv/chroot/squeeze64 /bin/bash`?

Comment: Added output from a verbose run. I notice that it's never running more than three setup scripts, which seems suspicious. Meanwhile, the plain chroot enters without issue, except that nothing is mounted (which is the part I'm trying to avoid by using schroot).

Comment: Does /var/lib/schroot/mount/ exist?

Comment: Yep, /var/lib/schroot/mount (and friends) exist. Permissions 755, owner root. Tried 777, same result.

Comment: Try [fakeroot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/dapper/fakeroot).

Comment: Which schroot version are you running? What is your current working directory when running `schroot`?

Comment: @warren, you added a bounty, can you add any additional details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[as i am see it is a bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=633671)

you should try to run the schroot command from the / directory or anyother but not some directory under /home.

Comment: The comments on that bug tracker link seems to indicate that the behavior is intentional, and the only issue, is the errors are not verbose enough.  So calling it a bug doesn't seem quite accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `bash` binary in your chroot-environment. Use `ldd bash` to check for the required libaries. Are all those libraries present in your chroot-lib-path?